# Expectation of expressions involving sample covariance matrix and inverse of covariance matrix

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

Let $y_{ij}$, $i=1,2,\cdots,n_j$ be a random sample from $N_p(\mu_j,\Sigma_j)$, $j=1,2$. Let $$\overline{y}_j=\frac{1}{n_j}\sum_{i=1}^{n_j}y_{ij} \hspace{2mm} \mathrm{and}$$
$$S_j=\frac{1}{n_j-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n_j}(y_{ij}-\overline{y}_j)(y_{ij}-\overline{y}_j)'$$ be the sample mean and variance, respectively. Let
$$n=n_1+n_2,$$
$$\overline{\Sigma}=\frac{n_2}{n}\Sigma_1+\frac{n_1}{n}\Sigma_2$$

How can I determine the closed forms of $E(S_1\overline{\Sigma}^{-1}S_1)$ and $E(S_1\overline{\Sigma}^{-1}S_2)$?

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you very much!